# How to centered Content from Label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

I have a `Grid`:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>       
        <RowDefinition Height="80*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
       Content="Text to center!" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5">
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

But at that variant I have a `Label` from all the `Grid` rows, but its `Content` goes to left side of the row.
How to make the `Content` centered ?
If I type `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` `Label` will be centered, but I need only `Content`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the horizontal alignment of the control's content use [`Control.HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) Property like this:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
```

Comment: Without any explanation as to why you're recommending this particular solution or how it works exactly, it's not clear to anyone whether or not this solution will work for them. Remember, you're not just answer for the OP, but you're also answering for everyone who finds your answer when looking for a solution a similar problem they might be having.